# Using custom styles from theme in material ui without makeStyles

Tags: javascript, material-ui, themes, formik-material-ui

I'm wondering if there is a way to access theme.customElements.acitonButton in MyComponent without having to use makeStyles? For example, can I somehow enter className={theme.customElements.actionButton}?

**theme.js**

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
   customElements: {
     actionButton: {
       backgroundColor: '#007AFF'
     }
   }
})


export default theme
```

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core'

// wondering if i can remove makeStyles and somehow access styles set in theme.js and add to <IconButton />?
const useStyles: any = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    actionButton: theme.customElements.actionButton
  })
})


const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = props => {
   const classes = useStyles()
   <IconButton className={classes.actionButton} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style of a Component or Element in the theme.
To do that, you need to create the a folder called overrides in theme folder and create a file with the same name as the component whose theme you want to override.

[image: a folder structure like this]

Then you can change the component style like this.

[image: component's overridden style]

```
export default {
elevation1: {
    boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px rgba(63,63,68,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(63,63,68,0.15)'
}
```

};

Also you need to add the theme provider to App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import ThemeProvider from '@material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import {darkBlueTheme} from './theme';
import Routes from './Routes';

function App() {
    return (
        <StateProvider reducer={appReducer} initialState={getInitialState()}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={darkBlueTheme}>
               App CODE HERE
            </ThemeProvider>
        </StateProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share how elevation1 component looks? are you naming the component elevation1 or passing some prop to it?

Comment: No, The component is MUIPaper (https://material-ui.com/components/paper/).
Since this is an override, you need to add the ThemeProvider - edited the original answer with the code.